# App crash when pressing a button in a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, subview

I've a big problem with a `scrollView`. I have this code and when i press a button that is in the `xib` file of "registerView" then the app crashes:

MainViewController.m:

ViewDidLoad:

```
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 1900);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


RegisterViewController *registerView = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
[scrollView addSubview:registerView.view];
```

"RegisterView" is added to a `scrollView`, but then when I push a button in "registerView" the app crashes with this log:

```
    2014-05-12 11:18:04.599 RegisterForm[16505:60b] -[UIScrollView modalPresentationStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f517200
2014-05-12 11:18:04.602 RegisterForm[16505:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIScrollView modalPresentationStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f517200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18a83709c 0x196c8dd78 0x18a83bd14 0x18a839a7c 0x18a7594ac 0x18d800a68 0x1000e76b4 0x18d70c2c0 0x18d70c044 0x18d7137dc 0x18d710ab0 0x18d78488c 0x1000e674c 0x18d7815cc 0x18d780fb8 0x18d77a9a0 0x18d70d530 0x18d70c720 0x18d77a0b0 0x190119128 0x190118c54 0x18a7f6fc8 0x18a7f6f28 0x18a7f514c 0x18a735b38 0x18d7792d4 0x18d7740e8 0x1000e7cd0 0x197277aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Button: 
RegisterViewController.h:

```
- (IBAction)btn_reset:(id)sender;
```

RegisterViewController.m:

```
    - (IBAction)btn_reset:(id)sender {
}
```

And I've tried to put a button in the `scrollView` instead but then i cant access to "textfields" info, so I need to put a button in the "RegisterView".

Comment: provide your button's action code, please

Comment: there's no code in the button, thats why this is weird, every time I'm adding a button, compile and pressed it crashes.

Comment: declare RegisterViewController *registerView in

Comment: so you don't have onTouchUpInside event handler for you button, but pressing on it causes crash???? O_o

Comment: Do you perhaps have a modal segue linked to the button?

Comment: no, i've declared the event, but nothing inside the event, its like this:
`- (IBAction)btn_reset:(id)sender {
}`

Comment: The thing is that I've always have been problems with buttons when I use them in addsubView, and I don't know how to fix it, its not the code, when I use addsubView I cant use any button there. Someone can help me? :S

Comment: ofc i've linked the IBAction with the button, thats why it crashes, if I don't declare any action with the button the app doesn't crash :S

Comment: Where is your button code? You haven't actually shared anything to do with a button. Even if all you have is the button declaration, this needs to be shared.

Comment: I'm sorry @Popeye , I've added to the question. Thanks for the advice and sorry again.

Comment: @Norolimba where do you declare your button? i.e. `@property (strong) UIButton *registerBtn;`?

Comment: For What You are using this `RegisterViewController *registerView = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
[scrollView addSubview:registerView.view];` ??

Comment: @yourwish what is your question?

Answer (score 4):

Declare the RegisterViewController *registerView in @interface or create a @property for it.

```
@interface XXXXX ()
{
 RegisterView *registerView;
}
```

OR

@property (nonatomic, strong) RegisterView *registerView;

Answer (score 2):

In your case `MainViewController` is not retaining `registerView` object. For retaining the instance you need to add it as the `childViewController` of your `MainViewController`,

```
RegisterViewController *registerView = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:registerView];
[scrollView addSubview:registerView.view];
```

No need of declaring any additional properties just for that, `UIViewController` will retain all its `childViewControllers`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that its related to not retaining the "RegisterView" class. While you are adding its view to scrollView the class itself is released as soon as the end of the function is reached.

Try declaring your RegisterView class as a property as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RegisterView *registerView;
```

And to add it in the scroll view:

```
self.registerView = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
[scrollView addSubview:self.registerView.view];
```