# App crashes ONLY when connected to XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, appdelegate

My Swift app only seems to crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when my app is connected to XCode and I'm debugging. If I unplug my device and then run the app, it works flawlessly.

The app crashes at:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not a crash. More likely you have an Exception breakpoint and you're hitting it.

Comment: Deleting all my break points does not make a different, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your function with below one:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {}
```

or

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> Bool {}
```

Comment: My application function already had the signature of your second recommendation.

Comment: You can give the test project so that we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

That could be a pointer deallocating issue in the memory. That would be great if you can post more details about the error/crash info that you got, so that we can help you better. There are some solutions that you can try from this existing post, which was the similar problem(EXC_BAD_ACCESS) as you have: http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access

Answer (score 0):

After a fiddling with the initial view controller I found that it only happened on the controller where my GMSMapView was. As it turns out, another user was having a similar problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264537/adding-google-maps-as-subview-crashes-ios-app-with-exc-bad/31445847#31445847)

It turns out upgrading to iOS 8.4 solved the issue immediately. While I didn't use Dave's brilliant work around, I still give all the props and kudos to him!

Thank you everyone for sticking with me during this dark time in my life.