# Adding GMSMarker to GMSMapView crashes on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, gmsmapview

I have code that loads a map view and places a marker on it. I have basically refactored my code to be Google sample code for adding a GMSMarker. The app runs no problem in the simulator (8.4), but when the marker code is added to the map on my iPhone 6 (`marker.map = mapView_`), the app crashes and I get the error in Xcode: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).

The mapView loads fine on the phone when I remove the `marker.map = mapView_` line of code. Here is the what I have reduced my code to in viewDidLoad: below.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:loc zoom:12.5];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.tiltGestures = NO;
mapView_.settings.rotateGestures = NO;
mapView_.delegate = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});

self.view = mapView_;

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = camera.target;
marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker.map = mapView_;
```

Comment: Xcode up to date, iPhone and Simulator running 8.4, and using Google Maps SDK of iOS v 1.10.1 installed through CocoaPods.

Comment: The app uses the GMSPlacePicker fine on the device using the longPress: delegate method (this drops a marker on the location). I made a new single view app with the above code and it runs on my phone. Is it possible my GoogleMaps sdk is corrupted? Some other conflict? I have no other pods installed.

Comment: Tried this solution (edit Scheme to disable GPU Frame Capture but still crashes my device. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264537/adding-google-maps-as-subview-crashes-ios-app-with-exc-bad/31445847#31445847

Comment: I think `camera.target` not getting value. Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043284/ios-google-maps-plotting-multiple-markers-issuesinfo-window-and-marker-repeatin/32043675#32043675

Comment: Thanks for the thought but it doesn't solve the issue. I started my app over with MapKit. I assume it was some obscure setting that got flipped somewhere in the project that was causing the crash...I ran out of patience and time trying to figure out what.

Comment: Did you get Solution ?
I also has same issue

Comment: I never did. I believe I restarted my Xcode project. I use google maps SDK extensively now and have not seen this issue again. It could have been an issue with the specific version I was using. I also think you are better off creating these mapviews strictly in code...xibs may get wires crossed.

Comment: Did anyone solve this? Also adding markers with images loaded from URLs ?