# ios google maps plotting multiple markers issues(info window and marker repeating)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

First i create a Map with user location

```
-(void)initGogleMapView{

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:1];

mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-64) camera:camera];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = camera.target;

marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker.map = mapView;
marker.title=@"Current Location";


}
```

Then i have an array of latitude and longitude and plot in for loop

```
   for(int i=0;i<[latLongArr count];i++)
         {
             GMSMarker *tempmarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
             tempmarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue],[[[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue]);
             tempmarker.title=[[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];
             tempmarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

             tempmarker.map = mapView;



         }
```

Markers are getting repeated with same title.Can anyone help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please give the array of the latitude and longitude

Comment: also i see my map is also repeating,I can see the same countries again and again when i scroll through map

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your Latitude and Longitude in array, it might be duplicates. Otherwise, follow steps :

At very first, add `GoogleMaps.bundle` and `GoogleMaps.framework` to your project.
And then when you want to implement google map, `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`, then set delegate `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>`.

Declare property in your `.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) GMSMapView *gMapView;
```

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:appDelegate.currentLoc.coordinate.latitude longitude:appDelegate.currentLoc.coordinate.longitude zoom:6];
self.gMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
self.gMapView.delegate = self;
self.gMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.gMapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
self.view = self.gMapView;

GMSMarker *curLocation = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
curLocation.title = @"Current Location";
curLocation.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
curLocation.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(appDelegate.currentLoc.coordinate.latitude, appDelegate.currentLoc.coordinate.longitude);
curLocation.map = self.gMapView;
```

Where you have added multiple markers to map.

```
for(int i=0;i<[latLongArr count];i++)
{
   GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[(NSDictionary *)[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue], [[(NSDictionary *)[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]);
   marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
   marker.title = @"Title";
   marker.snippet = @"Sub title";
   marker.map = self.gMapView;
}
```

Comment: actually i see my map is also repeating,I can see the same countries again and again when i scroll through map