# GMSMapView show blank map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I add GMSMapView into my screen but I only can see my position icon and the marker i added. Why i cant see the road, building, etc?

Here is my code :

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(latitude,
longitude: longitude, zoom: 11.5)
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)

mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

self.view = mapView

var marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
marker.title = location.name
marker.snippet = location.address
marker.map = mapView
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043284/ios-google-maps-plotting-multiple-markers-issuesinfo-window-and-marker-repeatin/32043675#32043675

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the main reason to have a blank map is that the key is not set properly

Did you set the API key correctly.

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:yourAPIKey];
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, i already add the API key but i forgot to update my bundle id. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another reason of getting blank map is that you haven't enable the API in your Google API console. Here is how, go to Library tab -> Select Google Maps SDK for iOS -> Click on the "Enable" button. Hope this helps for those still getting blank map after set the API key.

Comment: I've provided a key, enabled API but still get a blank map

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and API key was correct. The reason was in this lines of code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"ru" forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```