# Application crash without any error when i load google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am using google map new sdk download by cocoapods. All thing working fine till yesterday but suddenly today application is crash with out any error when i try to load the google map. Please see the below screen shot.

Any help is appreciable.

If i run application manually then it run fine but if i run it in debug mode it crash the application with xcode.

[image: updated image]

Comment: Please share the Exception/Error thrown by debugger..

Comment: No error are coming out.It just crash

Comment: Can I see `console` ?

Comment: @jeevanRao yes i upload new image wait for few minutes

Comment: @jeevanRao please see my updated image. And thanks for your comment

Comment: And it's only happen with older devices (version<9.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research i found the solution for this.

I change in the product>Schema>Edit Schema>Run>Option>GPU Frame Capture = Metal or Disable not get success with this. I found this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264537/adding-google-maps-as-subview-crashes-ios-app-with-exc-bad/31445847#31445847)

Comment: Did it Worked for you ?
Its not working for me, I Tried it...
I Tired to do it Metal, Open GLES & Disabled as well....
what to do with Metal API Validation ?

Comment: @MSAppTech yes it is working for me. but i have not conceptual sound for this

Comment: I tried all Options, but not working for me, let me know if you have any idea about it