# App crashes when running for first time when `FIRApp.configure()` is called

Tags: ios, firebase

I have a strange error with the new Firebase I am not able to figure out. I have enabled Firebase Analytics and Crashlog and I call `FIRApp.configure()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as the Docs say.

But when I run the app for the very first time it **sometimes** crashes without giving any detail information why. I can only provide this (always same) crashlog from the crash section of firebase. Anyone experiencing similar issues with the new Firebase?

```
___ZN3ggl10GLRenderer5frameEPNS_12RenderTargetEPNS_11RenderQueueE_block_invoke_2 + 4103720
___ZN3ggl10GLRenderer5frameEPNS_12RenderTargetEPNS_11RenderQueueE_block_invoke_2 + 4103704
___ZN3ggl10GLRenderer5frameEPNS_12RenderTargetEPNS_11RenderQueueE_block_invoke + 4102664
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 5304
_dispatch_client_callout + 5240
_dispatch_queue_drain + 54460
_dispatch_queue_invoke + 20348
_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 62348
_dispatch_worker_thread + 71984
_pthread_body + 15140
_pthread_start + 14984
thread_start + 4132
```

**Update**

I have now figured out that this crash only occurs if the fist view that gets loaded includes an MKMapView. Changing the initial view to an for e.g. UITableView fixes the crash. I will contact firebase support.

Comment: Did you found a solution? Moving the GoogleService PLIST to root did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

Move the GoogleService-Info.plist file you just downloaded into the root of your Xcode project and add it to **all targets**.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. The Firebase Setup Instruction just tells me to copy into my root dir, adding it to a target is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post a crash report with symbols so it would be easier to debug?
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264537/adding-google-maps-as-subview-crashes-ios-app-with-exc-bad), there may be a bug unrelated to Firebase. Can you try this and let us know if it solves the problems?

> In XCode, go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...
>
> Select the "Run" Tab on the left.
> Select the "Options" sub-tab on the
> top.
>
> Change "GPU Frame Capture" from "Automatically Enabled" or
> "OpenGL ES" to either "Metal" or "Disabled".
>
> This disables OpenGL ES
> frame capture, which isn't great, but allows you to continue debugging
> your builds.